# Realtime Data AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, request, timeout

im working in a freelance project, which make a control to a industrial process.
I'm making an app with the following frameworks:
AngularJS: Framework Frontend.
CodeIgniter: Framework Backend.
Database: mySQL
Sadly, because working conditions, i have some server restrictions, since initially the backend of this app will be mounted on a Shared Hosting.
One of the requirements is being able to upload data to a grid using this app. Using Tablets with internet access, is necessary to have access to this data synchronously between one or more users. The users basically will see a grid of data.
The problem is that when a user uploaded information, this should be seen immediately in another Tablet, which could also be uploading data.

I'm thinking in associate a timeout function which is updating the grid through a request http each "x" seconds, like this:

```
$timeout(function(){
   //http request reload the grid data
,3000);
```

For me, this solution is unstable under bad internet service, and doesn't look as an optimal solution.

Can someone give me some advice (preferably "angular-way") to approach this problem of synchronization without having to make this constantly http request, taking into account the technological restrictions of the server?

Comment: Read about websockets, e.g. http://socket.io

Comment: sockets are the best way to go, don't try reinvent the wheel, your approach doesn't scale and you'll find a tons of performance issues later